# option button (radio button) on each record of continuous form

Tags: ms-access

This is for a project in MS Access 2016. I'd like to implement a radio button toggle across all records displaying in a continuous form. only one record can have the toggle "on" so when it's clicked it has to reset the previous record's flag to off. I'm only finding help on radio button usage to select from multiple values of a field for one record, usually on single form. Can this be done?

[image: Example of continuous forms with radio buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *RecordSetClone* of the form:

```vb
Private Sub Active_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Records         As DAO.Recordset
    
    Me.Dirty = False
    
    If Me!Active.Value = True Then
        Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone
        Records.MoveFirst
        
        While Not Records.EOF
            If Records!Id.Value <> Me!Id.Value Then
                If Records!Active.Value = True Then
                    Records.Edit
                        Records!Active.Value = False
                    Records.Update
                End If
            End If
            Records.MoveNext
        Wend

        Records.Close
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Gustav, this is perfect. Works as advertised. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Radio button must be bound to a yes/no field then use UPDATE action SQL to make sure all records except current have field set to 0. Need a unique record identifier field such as autonumber.

```
Private Sub Option29_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tablename SET fieldname = 0 WHERE ID <>" & Me.ID
End Sub
```

Be aware that in a multi-user database users can conflict with each other and another solution will be needed. Depends what you need to do with the selected record.

Comment: For better performance and multi-user behavior, add `AND fieldname <> 0` to WHERE clause. So only the one existing "true" record is updated, not all of them.

Comment: June7 & Andre: WHen I try this solution I get error 3061 too few parameters.

Comment: Never mind, it works now - kinda, the new value saves into DB and previous rec gets set to 0, but the previous option button doesn't get deselected.

Comment: Try adding a Me.Requery or Me.Refresh command to code. However, you will find that this will put focus on first record of form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in easy way:

1- Add to your table a new Yes/No Field ( e.g named CurrentRec)

2- Put the Radio Button and link it to this field ( e.g named rdCurrRec)

3- For the radio button Set 'Enabled' property to False and 'Locked' property to 'True'. This will disable Click - Double Click and Hover response.

4- Put the following code

```
Dim PreBookmark(4) As Byte   'Save old bookmark

Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Not Me.NewRecord Then  'Make sure not on new record
        Me.rdCurrRec = True
        If (PreBookmark(0) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(1) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(2) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(3) <> 0) Then
            Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark = PreBookmark
            Me.RecordsetClone.Edit
            Me.RecordsetClone.Fields("CurrentRec") = False
            Me.RecordsetClone.Update
        End If
        PreBookmark(0) = Me.Bookmark(0)
        PreBookmark(1) = Me.Bookmark(1)
        PreBookmark(2) = Me.Bookmark(2)
        PreBookmark(3) = Me.Bookmark(3)
    Else  'If new record remove bullet from previous record
        If (PreBookmark(0) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(1) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(2) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(3) <> 0) Then
            Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark = PreBookmark
            Me.RecordsetClone.Edit
            Me.RecordsetClone.Fields("CurrentRec") = False
            Me.RecordsetClone.Update
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    'Remove the mark before exiting to avoid it appear next time to open the form in two places
    If Not Me.NewRecord Then
        If (PreBookmark(0) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(1) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(2) <> 0 Or PreBookmark(3) <> 0) Then
            Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark = PreBookmark
            Me.RecordsetClone.Edit
            Me.RecordsetClone.Fields("CurrentRec") = False
            Me.RecordsetClone.Update
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will not iterate all the data so for large number of records it will not delay the response as it works only on two records

Comment: Thanks mamadsp, but it isn't quite working. There are several issues The option button gets selected even on hover, but gets deselected when I click anywhere else. When I double click on the option, then click on another field of the same record, then on option of another record, I get 2 options selected. Also even though on the form an option is selected, the SQL table (I'm using linked tables), doesn't show any changes.

Comment: Hello again Lukasz. I improved the steps and code here to remove the issues you faced.
The benefit of the code here is that it interacts only with two records not all the records, so for large number of records you get the same performance without extra delay. I hope it is helpful for you.